# Jenkins Pipeline Global Library available outside workflow? (Extended Choice Parameter)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

is there any way how to make [Pipeline Global Library](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin) available even outside pipeline?

Namely I would like to use libraries I have there for [Extended Choice Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin), when using **groovy script** as value source.

There is an option to define **Groovy Classpath** for the **groovy script**. Not sure if that could somehow work.

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as such. Your best option would be to package the shared code (Java or Groovy) in a custom plugin depending on `script-security` and defining methods marked with the `@Whitelisted` annotation.

Comment: Was hoping for a different answer, but I understand. Thank you Jesse